# Polylang redirect doesn't work after second visit

Tags: wordpress, plugins, polylang

I have a default language with no slug, that is located at site.com, if I previously accessed the site at site.com/en or selected this language in the menu before, when I go to site.com I expect a redirect to site.com/en
But it doesn't happen. This functionality is not in the plugin by default?

Tried to write own solution (on PHP and js), but maybe plugin has

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.